# HTML form with table cell height problem

Tags: html, css

I have several forms like this:

```
<table  width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table_std">

        <tr id="exam_String_newValue_row">
          <td width="150" class="table_defaultHeaderColumn">Προκαθορισμένη Τιμές</td>
          <td width="802" class="table_defaultHeaderColumn" >
            <textarea name="textarea" id="textarea" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="150" class="table_defaultHeaderColumn">Διάγνωση - Αληθής</td>
          <td width="802">
            <input name="Exam_String_value" type="text" style="width:600px" id="textfield2" />
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td width="150" class="table_defaultHeaderColumn">Διάγνωση - Ψευδής</td>
          <td width="802">
            <input name="Exam_String_value" type="text" style="width:600px"  id="textfield2" />
         </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
```

css

```
  .table_defaultHeaderColumn {
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    .input_std {
        width: 200px;
    }
    .input_small {
        width: 4em;
    }

    .table_std {
        border-collapse:collapse;
    }
    .table_std td {
        padding-top: 1px;

        padding-bottom: 1px;
    }
```

The problem is the height of the cells.... isnt equal in all browsers...
any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found why...
The solution is to set vertical align to middle otherwise

Comment: Thanks, this just helped me with my issue I've been having for hours!

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any css changes, set margin and padding to 0 then change if needed. Also set line-height to 1em.

Comment: i have * {margin: 0;
padding:0;}
doesnt help:(

line height  for the textarea?
I will.. it will have an intelliessence like thing thats why i specify it.